# Creating Animations with Mouse Cursor in Mathematica

Tags: animation

Consider from [this link](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/image-and-signal-processing/dynamic-comparison-of-two-images.html?product=language) there is an animation at the bottom that, when played, shows a mouse cursor manipulating an interactive Wolfram element.

Is this animation created within Mathematica, and -- if so -- how?

Comment: You can click on "show complete Wolfram Language input" to see and copy the Mathematica source code for that